# read.csv stops reading at row 523924 even thouhg the file has 799992 rows

Tags: r, file, csv, size

Any idea why R would stop reading the file before it gets to the end?

I can open the file in excel, and it shows the full 799992. R reads only 65% of the file. I have saved the file as csv from Excel, but it did not change the number of rows R was able to read. In fact it stops reading at the exact same location every time.

I use the following command.

```
lem1 <- read.csv("lem1.csv", header=TRUE, sep =",")
```

I have the same issue on a similar data file, it only reads 57% of the file and stops "normally"

Comment: I'd take a look at that particular row and the rows around it... however, if you don't share the error and some of your data, we can't help much further.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  Providing relevant details is helpful in troubleshooting an issue.  Specifically, answers to: What happens when it stops?  What does it tell you?  What does the data look like (actual copy is preferred to the description), etc.

Comment: Try splitting your file into chunks and reading in sections around your stop-point.

Comment: it's also definitely worth looking into the `fread()` function of `data.table`, which is a little more robust and much faster than `read.table` ...

Comment: What does `read.csv("lem1.csv", skip = 523923)` do?

Comment: This would probably work, since the problem was in a specific line. I still did not see anything wrong with the line, but when I removed it or placed it at the end, ti worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

If the data has mismatched quotes or octothorpes (or in some OSes cntrl-Z's) then abnormal termination of the file read may occur. You can sometimes get satisfactory results by resetting the defaults for quote and comment.char:

```
lem1 <- read.csv("lem1.csv", header=TRUE, sep =",", 
                             quote="", comment.char="")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. There was a problem with the next line in the file. When I moved that line to the end of the file, it read the whole file. Maybe there was a hidden end of line character.