# read.csv - unknown character and embedded quotes

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I have a .csv that causes different problems with read.table() and fread().

There is an unknown character that causes read.table() to stop (reminiscent of [read.csv stops reading at row 523924 even thouhg the file has 799992 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955509/read-csv-stops-reading-at-row-523924-even-thouhg-the-file-has-799992-rows)). Excel, Notepad, and SAS System Viewer render it like a rightwards arrow (although if I use Excel's insert symbol to insert u2192 it appears different); emacs renders it ^Z.

fread() gets past the unknown character (bringing it in as \032) but there is another issue that prevents this from being the solution to my problem: the data set uses quotation marks as an abbreviation for inches, thus embedded (even mismatched) quotes.

Does anyone have any suggestions short of modifying the original .csv file, e.g., by globally replacing the strange arrow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this arrow show up more than once, or can you just navigate to the appropriate field, delete that character & then load the file?

Comment: The character shows up numerous times in each of the numerous files, each of which has approaching 10^6 rows - I'm currently embarking on the search-and-replace mission, which will be time consuming. My greater concern, though, is that I'll be modifying the inputs in an undocumented way.

Comment: Update: I realized it's a control (non-printing) character. On this thread (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-February/thread.html#187276) are two ideas: 1) read the file as raw bytes and replace the errant control character with nothing; 2) use something like perl (another correspondent suggested awk) to do the replacing before parsing in R. I've opted for the latter using a vbs script.

Answer (score 1):

In case of [Paul's file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68810356/3817004), I was able to read the file (after some experimentation) using `fread()` with the `cmd "unzip -cq"` and `quote = ""` parameters without error or warnings. I suppose that this might work as well with [Kristian's file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21195774/3817004).

On Windows, it might be necessary to install the  [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) beforehand.

```
library(data.table) # development version 1.14.1 used
download.file("https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-utl/extrfoia-master-dt2021-07-02.zip",
              "extrfoia-master-dt2021-07-02.zip")
txt1 <- fread(cmd = "unzip -cq extrfoia-master-dt2021-07-02.zip", quote = "")
```

**Caveat:** This will download a file of 38 MBytes

According to the [`unzip` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip), the `-c` option automatically performs *ASCII-EBCDIC conversion*.

The `quote = ""` was required because in at least one case a data field contained double quotes within the text.

---

I have also tried the `-p` option of `unzip` which extracts the data *without* conversion. Then, we can see that there is `\032` embedded in the string.

```
txt2 <- fread(cmd = "unzip -p extrfoia-master-dt2021-07-02.zip", quote = "")

txt2[47096, 1:2]
```

> ```
>    CUST-ID                 LEGAL-NAME
> 1: 1253096 JOHN A. GIANNAKOP\032OULOS
> ```

The `\032` does not appear in the converted version

```
txt1[47096, 1:2]
```

> ```
>    CUST-ID             LEGAL-NAME
> 1: 1253096 JOHN A. GIANNAKOPOULOS
> ```

We can search for all occurrences of `\032` in all character fields by

```
melt(txt2, id.vars = "CUST-ID", measure.vars = txt[, names(.SD), .SDcols = is.character])[
  value %flike% "\032"][order(`CUST-ID`)]
```

> ```
>      CUST-ID   variable                                    value
>  1:  1253096 LEGAL-NAME               JOHN A. GIANNAKOP\032OULOS
>  2:  2050751   DBA-NAME         colbert ball tax tele\032hone rd
>  3:  2082166 LEGAL-NAME             JUAN DE J. MORALES C\032TALA
>  4:  2273606 LEGAL-NAME                   INTRINSIC DM\032  INC.
>  5:  2300016 MAIL-ADDR1                            PO BOX \03209
>  6:  2346154 LEGAL-NAME           JOEL I GONZ\032LEZ-APONTE  CPA
>  7:  2384445 LEGAL-NAME                    NUMBERS CAF\032  PLLC
>  8:  2518214 MAIL-ADDR1                      556 W 800 N N\03211
>  9:  2518214 BUSN-ADDR1                      556 W 800 N N\03211
> 10: 13718109   DBA-NAME         World Harvest Financial Grou\032
> 11: 13775763 LEGAL-NAME Fiscally Responsible Consulting  LLC\032
> 12: 13775763   DBA-NAME Fiscally Responsible Consulting  LLC\032
> ```

This may help to identify the records of the file to fix manually.

Comment: The unzip parameter "-c" is the magic bullet.  If we use that to unzip the file, then R's built-in `read.csv` works fine.  I'm not in a position to test `datatable` tools in my work computer, but believe it would also be fine.  I've been testing ways to use R's built-in `unzip` functionality, but do not see how to pass the "-c" parameter to it.

Comment: look at this.  A system update "undoes" the cleanup.  The read does go through to end line, but the imported content now has bad character again. `1: 1253096 JOHN A. GIANNAKOP\032OULOS`

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem today, so its still there in R 4.0.5

The data I'm using is public, from the Internal Revenue service.  Somehow the unrecognized characters become "^Z" in the database. So far as I can tell, "^Z" gets inadvertently created when people enter characters that are not recognized by original program that receives. The IRS distributes a CSV file from the database.

In the example file I'm dealing with, there are 13 rows (out of 360,000) that have the ^Z in various spots. Manually deleting them one-at-a-time lets R `read.table` get a little further.  I found no encoding setting in R that made a difference on this problem.

I found 2 solutions.

1. Get rid of the "^Z" symbol with text tools before using read.csv.
2. Switch to Python. The `pandas` package function `read_csv`, with encoding as "utf-8" correctly obtains all rows. However, in the `pandas.DataFrame` that results, the unrecognized character is in the data, it looks like an empty square.

If you want an example to explore, here's the address: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-utl/extrfoia-master-dt2021-07-02.zip.  The first "^Z" you find is line 47096.

Comment: Please, can you check if [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68818861/3817004) using `fread()` is working for you?

Comment: I confirm @uwe's suggestion that unzipping with "-c" parameter solves problem, it eliminates the unexpected character and any text-based importer we try seems to work well.